# Are Microsoft Edge extension updates pushed to users automatically?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

When an extension update is published (Submission status is "In the Store")
How long does it take for the end users to get the update? 
Are they updated automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Observation: Extension was auto updated about 48 hours after the update was published in the store.